Seeking Expert Guidance for Raising a 10000 litre Water Tank on a Steel Stand without Modern Equipment
I live in a remote part of my country where malnutrition is gradually increasing due to drought. We have a borehole with a plastic 10000 litre tank that was raised onto a makeshift roof and is currently up 2.5m high which does not generate enough pressure for us to grow food to feed our children. It has been on this roof for just over 4 years and has been well beaten by the sun and bad weather. It serves about 250 members of my community. We would like to raise it 6m high with no modern equipment, without injury to any of the people raising it and damage to the tank as once it is damaged we will not be able to get any clean water, which means diarrhoeal diseases and malnutrition will increase even further. Bringing in professionals and modern equipment from the city will be very expensive for the community. I wonder whether I could get help from engineering experts within this forum. My community concerns are below.

Structural Safety:
What considerations should I keep in mind for building a cage and steel stand that can safely support a 10,000L water tank during and after lifting?

Lifting Mechanism and Load Distribution:
What would be the best DIY method to raise a steel stand (with the tank inside) 6m high, ensuring even load distribution, minimal risk of tipping and damage to the tank?

Material and Equipment Recommendations:
What types of ropes, pulleys, or winching systems would you recommend for safely lifting a structure of this weight without access to modern lifting equipment?

Safety Protocols:
What safety protocols and precautions should I implement when raising a heavy structure with a group of people to avoid accidents?

Potential Risks and Prevention:
What are the main risks or challenges I might face with this lifting method, and how can I prevent them (e.g., structural failure, shifts in weight, etc.)?


Anything else I may have missed will be gratefully received.
Responding to Ratchet Freak: Currently, there is a 50mm or 60mm pipe from the tank going down to the field and then reducing as it goes down to the field to 25mm or 20mm. Are you able to advise on the diameter size of these pipes as they go into the field. What size booster pump would be required. We have a soup kitchen beside the tank which we wanted to pipe water into. What pipe sizes would we need?
Thank you

You shouldn't need to worry about pressure when using water from your system, instead you probably worry about flow.
And low flow rate isn't a problem in and of itself. All that does is make it take longer to fill a pot. It's only a problem when you can't finish a chore (watering crops sounds like an issue).
You can fix flow without moving the tank by increasing the diameter of the pipe and making sure there are no blockages along the path. Or adding extra pipes to pull water. In other words find the bottleneck and fix it.
If you still want the pressure increased then instead of raising the tank you can use a booster pump to get the pressure required.
Or get a smaller 1 m³ tank up that high that is filled from the big tank through a pump which in turn feeds the rest of the community. It's a lot easier to make a structure to support 1 metric ton than it does to support 10.

The oldest way will be the easiest in your location. Please consider building an elevated stand as a hill consisting of rocks with gravel fill between them, to the height necessary to obtain gravity flow through the pipes you have at hand.
The slope of the hill to the top will serve as the assembly ramp; it is chosen so a work crew of people standing shoulder-to-shoulder can roll the empty tank to the top of it by hand and leg power. you can determine the necessary slope by experiment. If it is too steep for the crew, then you make the slope more gradual until success is achieved. once the tank is on top, you block the tank into position using more chunks of rock so it won't roll off.

Thank you so much for this idea.
